# Errors when attempting to update multiple column values in a MySQL DB using multiple WHERE clause values

Tags: python-3.x, sql-update, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm currently getting an error when attempting to update two columns of my MySQL database using `mysql.connector` and python 3.6. When I execute the command below I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order='1' WHERE (match_id='2051673' AND gametime=80 AND event_name='Pass')' at line 1

But, as far as I can tell, my command is perfectly legit. What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

```py
for item in pass_list:
    query = """UPDATE events SET event_key=%s AND order=%s 
               WHERE (match_id=%s AND gametime=%s AND event_name=%s)"""
    values = (item[0],item[7],item[1],item[2],item[3])
    cur.execute(query, values)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: The problem, as it happens, is that `order` is a SQL keyword. You can put backticks around it: `\`order\``.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're right and it never occurred to me, but should have.

Comment: You're welcome. The error message isn't particularly helpful in this case, haha.

Comment: If you post the answer I'll assign you credit. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers, answer posted. Happy coding to you!

Comment: As a follow-up, I'm no longer getting errors but it updates nothing, which is odd. I've ensured that all values involved are INT types on both sides and the values do actually match what's in the DB. I'm doing a commit as well. So not sure what I've gotten wrong. I'm not trying to update the private keys, just values at the end of the row.

Comment: Do a SELECT with your WHERE conditions to see if that returns anything.

Comment: Same exact WHERE statement works when doing a SELECT but no update actually occurs with UPDATE. I'm at a loss at the moment. Could this be a Connector bug?

Comment: Got it....Needed to use a comma instead of an AND. Correct syntax was "UPDATE events SET events.event_key=%s, events.order_id=%s WHERE"....

Comment: Ah, great catch! No AND allowed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For good or bad, `order` is a SQL keyword. You can put backticks around it:

```
`order`
```

Comment: this was exactly my problem hehehe